# Yii2 rest api сохранение в базу данных

Tags: yii2, api, post, rest

делаю rest api по шагам официальной документации  https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/quickstart.first-app. Столкнулся с недопониманием, как же добавить в таблицу user пользователей. Сказано через post-метод http://localhost/users. Но тогда он ставляет запись с ID=0 а все остальные поля пустые строки. Добавляю в тело запроса json с конкретными значениями, но это не помогает. Прошу помочь, т.к. гугл не помог)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась добавлением функций rules и attributeLabels  в модели.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]